# Making MainWindow visible when pushButton in Dialog in clicked in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to switch back to the original MainWindow when a "Push Button" in Dialog is clicked. I have tried the following which makes a copy of the MainWindow visible and I cannot edit anything in there. Please help.

Here's MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Here's MainWindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "dialog.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Dialog *dialog=new Dialog();
    dialog->setModal(false);
    dialog->show();
}
```

Here's Dialog.h

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

Here's Dialog.cpp:

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    MainWindow *main=new MainWindow();
    main->show();
    main->activateWindow();
    main->raise();
    main->setFocus();
}
```

Here's main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: I think you will have to provide more code so we have some context. Also, if you "cannot edit anything in there" then maybe another dialog is being displayed which is modal? And, why do you make a new MainWindow, is that intentional or just an attempt to switch back to the "original" MainWindow? Your question is unclear. Please add more details or you risk it getting closed.

Comment: Full code provided above as per the comment

Comment: You could use signals/slots. Emit a signal once the button is clicked and catch it in your MainWindow class.

Comment: Update: I made my Dialog modeless by using show() instead of exec (as edited above in MainWindow.cpp). However, still new MainWindow is popping up and not the original one. How can I solve that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MainWindow cannot be shown on top of a modal dialog (it can, if the dialog is modeless). See [QDialog::setModal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#modal-prop).

- If the dialog is modal, the only way to bring the MainWindow back on front is to hide/close de dialog. Actually, you may manage to show it on top of the dialog (with the code you posetd), but it will be blocked for user input as the modal dialog is the only one that will accept user inputs untill closed.
- If dialog is modeless, use `raise()` (and/or `setFocus()` `activateWindow()` to be tested) to bring the MainWindow back to front, but then, you need to have a way to access the MainWindow instance, you should not create a new one. Easiest is to pass MainWindow pointer to the dialog constructor so that dialog can store it as an attribute ans bring it to front upon button click.

For instance:

```
class def : public QDialog
{
public:
    def( QMainWindow* parent );

    ...

private:
    QMainWindow* m_parent;
};

def::def( QMainWindow* parent ) : QDialog( parent ), m_parent( parent )
{

}

void def::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    m_parent->activateWindow();
    m_parent->raise();
    m_parent->setFocus();
}

// then, pass MainWindow reference to dialog upon creation
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Dialog *dialog=new Dialog( this );
    dialog->setModal(false);
    dialog->show();
}
```

Comment: Update: I made my Dialog modeless by using show() instead of exec (as edited above in MainWindow.cpp). However, still new MainWindow is popping up and not the original one. How can I solve that issue?

Comment: If you use the code I posted, the original main window will be shown, not a new MainWindow (unless you create a new one). The dialog must have a pointer to the main window to be brougth to front.